# JSF insert space between components in same <div>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Good Evening, i want to know how to insert space between JSF components that lies in same `<div>` without using `<h:outputText value="&#160;" />` i used it and in order to insert the desired space that i want i repeated these tag around 50 times! what are the alternative approaches to do that, these is the `<div>` :

```
<div
    style="width: 100%; font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px; background-color: gray">
    <h:outputText value="&#150;" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Notifications ">
        <h:graphicImage
            value="/resources/images/lunapic_136698680056094_2.gif" />
    </h:outputLabel>

    /// insert space here

    <h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
        <h:outputText value="Welcome,Islam"></h:outputText>
    </h:outputLink>

    <p:tooltip for="lnk">
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/sofa.png" />
    </p:tooltip>

</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `<br/>`? or `&nbsp;`, if you mean horizontal spacing

Comment: it inserts a new line, i want a space not a new line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normally to be achieved using [CSS](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/), e.g. via the `margin` property. CSS works on HTML and JSF is in the context of the current question merely a HTML code generator. You should ignore the JSF part in the question and concentrate on the JSF-generated HTML output in order to achieve the requirement. You can see it by rightclick, *View Source* in a webbrowser. If the HTML needs some altering, then change the JSF source code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML.

E.g.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Notifications" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
```

*(please note that using `style` is a poor practice; CSS should preferably be declared in a `.css` file which you import via `<h:outputStylesheet>` and reference via `styleClass` attribute)*

Again, this all has nothing to do with JSF. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. If you're brand new to basic [HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/)/[CSS](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/) and thus doesn't exactly understand what JSF is producing, then I strongly recommend to take a JSF-pause and learn those basics first.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<h:outputLabel>` generates a HTML `<label>` element, but you don't seem to have any HTML input element associated with it. You're in essence abusing the label element for the wrong purpose. [Understanding basic HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/) and [how to write semantic HTML](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/) and knowing what HTML output [those JSF components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) exactly generate should push you far in the right direction. In this particular case, you should likely be using `<h:outputText>` instead.

Answer (score -1):

To insert spaces between components in the same line, you can use img tag with a 1x1 clear image. (**Note**: this should be the last resort until other options exhausted, see discussion below)

```
<img width="100" height="10" src="/path-to/dot_clear.gif" />
e.g.
<img width="100" height="10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanluo/jsf/master/images/dot_clear.gif" />
```

Enter desired width; for height any number between 1 to 10 will do.
By default, the unit of width and height is pixel

To get a copy of the dot clear image and save it to local resources from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanluo/jsf/master/images/dot_clear.gif

Right click on the content area and Save as...

Comment: Why is this better/more modern than using css? For me doing things like this is from the pre IE8 era (or IE7). Browsers have since advanced a lot and quirks are not needed to be fixed with workarounds like this

Comment: @Kukeltje I just provided  a solution and gave a choice to users, not comparing it with css or other better solutions. BTW, as of PrimeFaces 5.3.RC2, <p:spacer> use img tag behind the scenes, same idea I mentioned

Comment: Yes, but think of visibly impared users. Pages with all kinds of (to them) useless images, makes the page impossible to use. See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C18.html . The fact that the `p:spacer` exists does not mean it should be used. There is (afaics) no valid reason today to use a solution like this.

Comment: We had a project which used complicated css, in order to insert desired spaces between components in a page, developers tried margins, padding, block, etc. w/o success, they caused issues in layout, font color, background color, etc. Image spacer was the solution at that time. Agreed with you points though, I updated the answer with a note.

Comment: Thanks... downvote removed (still no upvote though ;-))